# Ignition Switch Issues

Tags: electrical, daewoo

I have a 1999 Daewoo Lanos Auto 
For some reason my ABS, brake and engine warning lights have come on permanently When this happened the wipers, windows and heater all stopped working, I had to call out the AA to get me home and when he checked he said i had a lose connection on the ignition switch.
Did he mean the ingition coil?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If he said your ignition switch, he's talking about where you put your key in to start the vehicle.

Comment: @paulster2 Where you put your key is an ignition lock cylinder which has no wires it's all mechanical. The ignition switch is the plastic device behind the lock cylinder that will have the contacts and wires. It may seem I'm being overly specific but in this situation I think it would be wise to differentiate between them since the diagnosis was a loose wire connection.  replacing the place where you put the key would do nothing but cause further confusion from someone thinking they already changed the "swicth"

Comment: The ignition switch is bad, or some relay in the fuse box has gone bad.

Answer (score 0):

Some electrical system in your car can be turned on without the key, but others won't operate until the key is turned on. The AAA person reasoned since the non-functioning systems all require the key to be in the ON position then the Ignition Switch,which is activated by the key, is at fault.
A person with a 5-dollar Circuit Tester will start poking around the fuse block(s) and to see which systems have no power.